# Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) while creating linked list queue (along with a stack function)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, queue

So my assignment is to create a "juggler" program that pushes/pops values from a stack function and enqueues/dequeues values from a queue function, and it also passes these values between functions. For example... if I pop a value from the stack, it is entered into the "outQueue", etc.

When I tested the functionality of my stackADT function, it worked fine. Once I added the Queue function, I started to get the Segmentation fault error. I have researched it for days and still can't figure it out. Disclaimer: the program is not yet at the stage of passing values between the stacks and queues, I'm just trying to get both functions to run correctly.

Can anyone look at my code and figure out why I'm getting this error??

queueADT.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "queueADT.h"

struct qnode{
   int data;
  struct qnode *next;
};

struct q_type{
    struct qnode *front;
    struct qnode *rear;
};
static void terminate(const char *message)
{  
   printf("%s\n", message);
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

Queue createq(void)
{  
   Queue q = malloc(sizeof(*q));

   if(q == NULL)
   {  
      terminate("Error in create: queue could not be created.");
   }
   q->front = NULL;
   q->rear = NULL;
   return q;
}

void destroyq(Queue q)
{  
   make_emptyq(q);
   free(q);
}

void make_emptyq(Queue q)
{  
   while(!is_emptyq(q))
     dequeue(q);
}

bool is_emptyq(Queue q)
{
   return q->front== NULL && q->rear == NULL;
}
bool is_full(Queue q)
{
   return false;
}    


void enqueue(Queue q,int x)
{
   struct qnode *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct qnode));
   if(front == NULL && rear == NULL)
   {
        front = rear = temp;
        return;
   }
   temp->data = x;
   temp->next = q->rear;
   rear = temp;
}

int dequeue(Queue q)
{
   struct qnode *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct qnode));
   temp = q->front;
   int i = temp->data;
   if(is_emptyq(q))
   {
        terminate("Error in pop: queue is empty.");
   }
   if(front == rear)
   {
        front = rear = NULL;

   }else
   {
        front = front->next;
   }

   free(temp);
   return i;

}
```

queueADT.h(header):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H

#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct q_type *Queue;
struct qnode *front;
struct qnode *rear;
Queue createq(void);
void destroyq(Queue q);
void make_emptyq(Queue q);
bool is_emptyq(Queue q);
bool is_fullq(Queue q);
void enqueue(Queue q, int x);
int dequeue(Queue q);


#endif
```

And here is the runner, it's supposed to run both the Stack functions and the Queue functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sqjuggler.h"
#include "stackADT.h"
#include "queueADT.h"

int main(void)
{

   Stack s1, s2;
   Queue q1, q2;
   int n;
   int l;

   s1 = creates();
   s2 = creates();
   q1 = createq();
   q2 = createq();

   enqueue(q1, 1);
   enqueue(q2, 2);
   enqueue(q1, 3);
   enqueue(q2, 4);

   l = dequeue(q1);
   printf("%d q1\n", l);
   l = dequeue(q2);
   printf("%d q1\n", l);

   push(s1,1);
   push(s1,2);

   n = pop(s1);
   printf("popped %d s1\n", n);
   push(s2, n);
   n = pop(s1);
   printf("popped %d s1\n", n);
   push(s2, n);

   destroys(s1);

   while(!is_emptys(s2))
   printf("popped %d s2\n", pop(s2));

   push(s2,3);
   make_emptys(s2);
   if(is_emptys(s2))
   printf("s2 is empty");
   else printf("s2 is not empty");

   destroys(s2);
   return 0;


}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Now is the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Especially learn how to use a debugger to catch the crash as it happens, how you can use it to locate where it happens in your code, and how you can then examine variables and their values.

Comment: Delete the `front` and `rear` declarations from `queueADT.h`, and then fix your code.

Comment: @user3386109 When front and rear are deleted from queueADT.h are deleted, I get multiple errors that front and rear are undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: Yes, that's right. So now you need to fix the code. Look at the definition of `struct q_type`.